# Como ler arquivos de texto e colocar as palavras em um vetor?

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Eu preciso fazer um código que leia um arquivo de texto (txt) e salvar somente as palavras nas posições de um `vetor`, abaixo segue meu código:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");

    char x[100];

    while((x[i] = fgetc(file)) != ' ' && x[i] != '\t')
    {
        i++;
    }

    j = 1;

    x[i+1] = '\0';
    printf("%s", x);

    fclose(file);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Mas a partir disso eu não sei como fazer.

Comment: Você já iniciou? o que você fez até agora?

Comment: Eu leio a primeira palavra até o primeiro espaço, mas depois eu não sei continuar lendo e armazenando.

Comment: Poste o código.

Answer (score 4):

Você tem que ter em mente que um vetor de string em **C** é na verdade uma matriz de `char`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
char* palavras[50];
```

Acima eu declarei um vetor com um ponteiro que aponta para a palavra. Este vetor tem capacidade de armazenar 50 palavras, e o numero de caracteres das palavras pode ser qualquer um, porque vai depender do tamanho da palavra que estará no arquivo `palavras.txt`.

Eu assumi que a estrutura do conteúdo do arquivo de texto `palavras.txt` esteja da seguinte forma:

```
computador
gato
mundo
cachorro
casa
stack
over
flow
```

Aqui segue um exemplo de um programa que lé as palavras do arquivo de texto e armazena no vetor `palavras` as palavras lidas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int numPalavras = 0;
    char* palavras[50];
    char line[50];

    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("palavras.txt", "r");

    if (arquivo == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, arquivo) != NULL)
    {
        //Adiciona cada palavra no vetor
        palavras[i] = strdup(line);

        i++;

        //Conta a quantidade de palavras
        numPalavras++;
    }

    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < numPalavras; j++)
        printf("\n%s", palavras[j]); //Exibi as palavras que estao no vetor.

    printf("\n\n");

    fclose(arquivo);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Saída do programa:

```
computador

gato

mundo

cachorro

casa

stack

over

flow
```

Repare que eu tive que usar a função `strdup` para retornar o ponteiro da string que esta armazenada em `line` que neste caso é a palavra, sem ela todos os ponteiros das palavras iriam apontar para o mesmo local, se não me engano apontaria para a ultima palavra do arquivo `flow`, para comprovar basta fazer o teste substituindo a linha `palavras[i] = strdup(line);` por `palavras[i] = line;` para ver o resultado.

Para saber mais sobre a função `strdup` veja esta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252782/5429980).

Fontes:
[Reading lines from c file and putting the strings into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502314/5429980).
[How do I create an array of strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088667/5429980)

Comment: Esse programa não faz o que promete. Só coloca as palavras do texto em um vetor se cada linha tiver somente uma palavra.

Comment: @Claudius o AP não especificou isso na pergunta, e eu respondi o que foi pedido. Isso não tem relação de como o arquivo esta organizado porque ele nem foi exemplificado na pergunta.